# Where i can find "/boot/vmlinuz" when "/boot" not exists

Tags: linux, boot, grub

Hi all I'm new here and I want to ask where i can find vmlinuz without "/boot" directory...
So system normally boots (Chrome OS) All working perefectly from pendrive But when I want dual boot I need Grub4Dos and There's problem I don't know where is the vmlinuz file to put it in "menu.lst"

P.S sorry For bad English

Closed: I find a way:
I Find /syslinux/vmlinuz.A File in /dev/sdb12 i copied all /dev/sdb12 contents to newly created /boot directory on ROOT-A and changed menu.lst kernel file to: /boot/syslinux/vmlinuz.A

Comment: Where did you get your ChromeOS build?

Comment: I build my own Chromium OS and upgraded to Chrome OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically, the kernel was stored in the root directory `/`. The `/boot` directory appeared only when a few distributions started to propose several kernels to boot on and several other facilities (such as `memtest` like applications).

So, if you miss a `/boot` directory, the kernel (`vmlinuz` in your case) is more likely to be at `/`.

Comment: I can only see file "postinst" is it kernel file?

Comment: Probably not, usually `postinst` is the log of the installation of the system. I looked a bit around, have something like `/sys-kernel/chromeos-kernel` in your file-system ?

Comment: Nope. I don't Have /sys-kernel directory P.S I searched "/" Filesystem and i don't find vmlinuz file

Comment: Ok i finally did it I found /syslinux/vmlinuz.A File in boot partition (/dev/sdb12) i copied all contents to newly created /boot directory on ROOT-A and changed menu.lst kernel file to: /boot/syslinux/vmlinuz.A anyway Thx for help :)

Comment: Sorry to not have been more helpful. :-/ I don't know ChromeOS distribution at all. You should consider filling up an answer to your own question. It may be useful for others !

Comment: Dont't worry. Just Thx for answering me :)

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing directly to that address.  eg cd /boot/vmlinuz  I know some filing systems don't allow you to stop in a given directory (eg Netware).